# iPad: getting back to initial screen after watching podcast

Tags: ipad, ipod.app

I use the iPod application on my iPad to watch podcasts most days, but after watching a podcast it seems impossible to get back to the initial screen (which shows when the app is launched) without quitting the app and starting it up again. Is there some sort of secret to getting back the the initial screen?

Comment: I've opened up a meta discussion about [tag standardization](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121/tag-standardization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify if it's an Audio podcast or a Video podcast.

in a Video Podcast, the iPod App quits and Video app lunches with the selected Video Podcast, so when you press the DONE button you are in the Videos app

iPod-app

[image: iPod app]

on tap on the Podcast, opens in Videos app

[Videos app http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-09-22_0911_001.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-09-22_0911_001.png)

so, you can't go back because you are actually in other app... though the new **iOS 4.2** makes that easy ;)

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice that the app is actually switching >.< thank you :-)